# how to align text view to the right of Image view within Linearlayout Dynamically in android

Tags: android

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
ImageButton imb=new ImageButton(this);

ll.addView(tv);
tv.setSingleLine();

tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

tv.setText(myString1);
```

This is my code and I'm able to display data in `textView` now. But I want to put one `imageButton` to the left of `textView` so that will work as cancel strip. but I'm having a problem. How can I set `imageButton` left of text view programatically?

Comment: Set property orientation to horizontal for linear layout. Then add imageview first and then add textview.

Comment: i m able to display text vew But i want to set image Button left of text view within same linear lay Out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions for your question. You can use the below code if you just want to show image on the right of textview.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon,0, 0,0);
```

or else

set orientation of your linearlayout as Horizontal and add the imageview first and then textview second. So they will be aligned as your requirement.

Below is the example.

```
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   ImageButton imb=new ImageButton(this);
imb.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   ll.addView(imb);
   ll.addView(tv);
```

Comment: can u please Explain coz i have to apply Onclick fucntion Image Button for cancel that TExt view

Comment: can u please tell me code for second solution according to my requrement

Comment: if you want to apply onClick() functionality then you use second option as I explained above

Comment: But i m having Problme to apply Image Button  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
   ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   
   
   
   
   
   
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  Button imb=new Button(this);
  imb.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
     
    ll.addView(tv);
    tv.setSingleLine();
    
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  
   tv.setText(myString1);

Comment: just Edit my code and set One Image Button coz its appergin when set it

Comment: in your code you haven't added button, you just added it and check

Comment: NO dear Still having Problem not displaying data and imgae view not displaying i think there will Problme in height and width

Comment: Image Button is not appering while i set image also how i ll set textview height and width for text view

Comment: http://pastie.org/5579573  this i have apply still imageButton is not displaying oNly textview is coming with morqueestyle data